# Trigger: allow updates to "no column except foo"

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger, row-level-security

Let's say we have a table like:

```
                         Table "someschema.todo"
    Column    |    Type      | Nullable |             Default
--------------+--------------+----------+----------------------------------
 id           | integer      | not null | nextval('todo_id_seq'::regclass)
 contract_id  | integer      | not null |
 title        | text         |          |
 description  | text         |          |
 status       | todo_status  |          | 'INCOMPLETE'::todo_status
Foreign-key constraints:
    "todo_contract_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (contract_id) REFERENCES contract(id)
```

Row Level Security is enabled, and we'll assume that the rules have been set up appropriately with one exception: a user type who would not normally be allowed to `UPDATE` rows in this table is required to be able to bump the `status` column from one `enum` value to another. Say, from `INCOMPLETE` to `PENDING`. That user type also needs to be able to `UPDATE` the table at other times (depending on conditions related to the `contract_id` fkey) so we can't just use a blanket column grant.

Arguably, this could make the column a candidate for inclusion in a new `todo_status` table, but let's just rule that out for the moment. Now we could write a trigger to check every column by name to see if it had been modified and only allow those queries which modify `status` and nothing else... but that seems fragile (what if we later add another column?) and painful.

Is there a way within a trigger to allow a modification of "no column *except* `status`"? In other words, "deny access unless the only column modified is `status`".

Supplemental: is there a way to accomplish this using a `check_expression` or `using_expression` within `CREATE POLICY` that I haven't considered? I've been assuming that because we don't have the `NEW` values in `using_expression` or the `OLD` values in `check_expression`, I can't use RLS to achieve what we need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger would be relatively robust

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_update()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_key TEXT;
    v_value TEXT;
    valid_update boolean := true;
BEGIN
    FOR v_key, v_value IN select key, value from each(hstore(NEW))  each LOOP
        if (coalesce(v_value,'') != coalesce((hstore(OLD) -> v_key),'')) then
            if (v_key != 'status')  then
                valid_update := false;
            end if;
        end if;
    END LOOP;
    if (valid_update) then
        raise info 'good update';
        return NEW;
    else
        raise info 'bad update';
        return null;
    end if;
 END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger validate_update before update on someschema.todo 
for each row execute procedure validate_update();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting (and introduced me to `hstore`!)